# how to share a folder between windows 10 and an Ubuntu which is installed on virtual box?

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing

I want to share a folder which is on one of my drives on windows 10 with the ubuntu i've installed on virtual box. 
What should i do on both of the operating systems?

Comment: There nothing to do in either. It's all about settings in the virtualization software you're using, Virtualbox in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that Windows 10 is the Host system for Virtualbox and Ubuntu is the guest.  If that is the case:

You may use the "shared folders" feature from the Guest Additions to provide this functionality. (Obviously this means that Guest Additions must be installed in the guest.)

Under Devices in the top menu, select Shared Folders and Shared Folders Settings.  Click on the green folder with a plus on it on the left of the screen and browse to the folder on the Host you wish to share. Once located, tick the boxes for your chosen options Read-only, Auto-mount, Make Permanent.  If you wish to use the folder in the future, I suggest ticking Auto Mount and Make Permanent.

There is one additional step that is sort of hard to find to make this work.  You must add your user to the shared folders group in the Ubuntu guest and reboot it.

`sudo adduser [username] vboxsf`